# Add Certifikate in traefik for Service discovered from rancher

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik, rancher

i have successfully configured traefik 1.5.4 to work and talk with rancher.

I'd like to add a few more services to rancher by configuring the services labels.
One service has a different domain (not mine) as the others with a SSL Cert i get from the owner of that domain.

So how do i configure that with Rancher Labels.

I know how to do this in the traefik.toml but im curious if theres a way to configure that without touching the toml file everytime.

Also i think it quite elegant if the services are the owner of their configuration.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: So i think the only way is to add a certificate file for a Host with the "file" provider  - maybe anyone knows if this is right and if it will change with 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

Label "traefik.frontend.rule" can take multiple Destinaations e.g. 
"Host: a.url.cloud,b.url.cloud"